# Template property of type ControlTemplate accepts both 'DataTemplate & ControlTemplate' in style?

Tags: wpf, silverlight-4.0, datatemplate, controltemplate

Why are we able to assign either of `DataTemplate` or `ControlTemplate` to the `Template` property which is of type `ControlTemplate` in the below markup:-

```
<Style TargetType="ListBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <!--
            Visual Studio Intellisense shows
            both ControlTemplate and 
            DataTemplate here.
            -->
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is just that the Intellisense isn't smart enough (actually for me VS2010 it shows any XAML as valid, not just ControlTemplate and DataTemplate).  The [documentation on ListBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.listbox_properties%28v=vs.110%29)  shows that in fact only *ControlTemplate* is valid.  And this is confirmed if you declare the template as a direct child of ListBox, instead of as a *Style*:

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Template>
        <!-- Intellisense lists only ControlTemplate here -->
    </ListBox.Template>
</ListBox>
```